# Triangle, i am having a triangle with AaD (different sides) i dont understand need help

Tags: triangles, angle

[image]

What do i do when the length of BC(a) is on the opposite side of A (other side of h).
I cant find any info about it anywhere. I am not very good at math, so if you can explain it as you would to a child i would appreciate it alot. I understand that cosinus and sinus are cordinates and a button on the calculator, cant figure out what order to press it

Comment: Wait, what length would you like to calculate? And is it a length in the given triangle, or do you want to make some modification to it?

Comment: What is the question? If you are attempting to calculate some length or angle, better say which.

Comment: Ì think i got it. I found out that the 90 degree angle of H should be treated as i would had i known C, i calculate the whole thing in 2 seperate pieces, first the left side and then the right side. Right?

Comment: I need to calculate, 
a) calculate Angle C
b) calculate Length of AH
c) calculate the area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- $48^2 + HC^2 = 107^2$
- $\tan 54^\circ = \cfrac{48}{AH}$

Comment: Thank you, you guys are freaking awesome! glad i found this site

Comment: I am a little slowbrained at the moment, ive been sitting 24 hours straight due to this assignment deadline, but im glad you gave me something to work with. And happy to know that it can be solved lol